# FileNotFoundException when exporting .jar

Tags: java, jar, applet, inputstream, filenotfoundexception

In my client/server app I need to send some file (`.txt`, `.doc`, etc.) from the client to the server. When I run my code in Eclipse it works, but when I export the signed JAR of the Applet it doesn't. It throws a `FileNotFoundException`. I tried saving file in several ways without success.

```
public static boolean saveFile(File sourceFile) throws IOException {

    DirectoryChooserDialog dialog = new DirectoryChooserDialog();
    filePath = dialog.getDestinationFolder();
    if (filePath != null) {
        InputStream inputFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(""+sourceFile);

        filePath += File.separator + sourceFile.getName();

        FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

        int byteLetti = 0;
        while ((byteLetti = inputFile.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            outputFile.write(buffer, 0, byteLetti);
            outputFile.flush();
        }

        inputFile.close();

        outputFile.close();

        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Alternative code used:

```
FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
```

Or

```
InputStream inputFile = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(""+sourceFile);
```

Or

```
InputStream inputFile = FileSaving.class.getResourceAsStream(""+sourceFile);
```

Original code and every alternative work in Eclipse and stop working when exported.

Comment: If your application creates data dynamically, you should use system specific storage for storing application data. Some kind of `java.io.tmpdir` or `user.home`. Not try to find them inside .jar, because it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

This code is looking a file on the classpath. If there's no a file there it throws FNF. When you work in Eclipse your file is probably in the src, so it's copied to bin. After you archived a file to the jar you can access it either `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`

```
InputStream inputFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(sourceFile.getName())
```

or using URL. For example

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file:/c:/path/to/my.jar!/myfile.txt"); 
JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream inputFile = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error: The method getInputStream() is undefined for the type File

Comment: I tried using your code but I don't understand how to merge it with my code. Would you do it for me? Thanks

Comment: The same result, OK on eclipse, KO on Jar.

Comment: Made a couple of attempts with 2 type of files: `IO error write: playbasket_8.doc
IO error write: playbasket_8.pdf` (running on eclipse I get those errors on the Console, but the file are correctly created in the file system)

Comment: I have signed mine, in fact it doesn't throws any security exceptions.

Comment: Note that I have hardcoded the outFile because you removed the DirectoryChooserDialog to select the destination folder.

Comment: Yes the DirectoryChooserDialog is wrapping a JFileChooser. I will check some other things.

Comment: The only problem with your last solution is that I can't pack the file within the jar because it's created on runtime by the app itself. (Thanks a lot for your help!)

Comment: Where? On the client side or server side?

Comment: If you need "to send some file (.txt, .doc ...) from the client to the server" you can't do it with this code. You need fileupload applet that communicate with servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your resources manually into the jar.

To do so, use 7zip or winRar or anything else, right click and "open archive".
Then drag-and-drop your resouces (e.g. png's etc.) to the appropriate folder (usually root).

Comment: Maybe this would work but my app creates the resources "dinamically".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after becoming mad.
Windows didn't have privileges to open the files.
So run your browser with Administrator privileges and it will work.